# Cum Max Sum in Polars

Tags: python-polars

In the following dataframe, I want to populate the column `cum_max_sum` using the columns `minimum` and `to_add`. How can I achieve this using Polars operations?

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ prev_cum_max_sum ┆ minimum ┆ to_add ┆ cum_max_sum │
│ ---              ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64              ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64         │
╞══════════════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ null             ┆ 1       ┆ 5      ┆ 6           │
│ 6                ┆ 4       ┆ 6      ┆ 12          │
│ 12               ┆ 13      ┆ 7      ┆ 20          │
└──────────────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

Explanation:

`max(null, 1) + 5 = 6`

`max(6, 4) + 6 = 12`

`max(12, 13) + 7 = 20`

Comment: My first inclination is that your best bet for performance is to make a ufunc with numba because polars expressions aren't iterative so there's not a particularly clean way to handle the row-wise logic that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polars is vectorized so you can't really condition the next value on the previous value except with clever uses of `cum___` functions or maybe dynamic groupbys.

You can take advantage of numba's ability to make vectorized ufuncs and polars's ability to use ufuncs ([mostly](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10512)) seemlessly.

```
import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n)', nopython=True)
def g(x,y, res):
    res[0]=x[0]+y[0]
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        if res[i-1]>x[i]:
            res[i]=res[i-1]+y[i]
        else:
            res[i]=x[i]+y[i]
```

Now you have a ufunc called `g` which can do what you need.

Let's make a bigger df and try it out.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
df=pl.DataFrame({'minimum':np.random.randint(0,50,100),
                 'to_add':np.random.randint(0,5,100)})
print(df.with_columns(cum_max_sum=g(pl.col('minimum'), pl.col('to_add')))[0:8])
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ minimum ┆ to_add ┆ cum_max_sum │
│ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64         │
╞═════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 9       ┆ 0      ┆ 9           │
│ 36      ┆ 1      ┆ 37          │
│ 15      ┆ 1      ┆ 38          │
│ 0       ┆ 0      ┆ 38          │
│ 49      ┆ 2      ┆ 51          │
│ 28      ┆ 3      ┆ 54          │
│ 25      ┆ 0      ┆ 54          │
│ 29      ┆ 4      ┆ 58          │
└─────────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

There are a couple gotchas that this avoids:

1. anything with strings won't work with numba because of the different ways each library treats them. (I might be wrong here so I'd be happy to be corrected)
2. If you create a ufunc with more than 2 inputs then you have to use structs to input them (see my linked github issue)

Additionally, you can wrap that `g` into an expression which you then monkey patch to the `pl.Expr` namespace if you need to use it a lot, like this:

```
def gexpr(self, to_add):
    if isinstance(to_add, str):
        to_add=pl.col(to_add)
    return g(self, to_add)
pl.Expr.g=gexpr
print(df.with_columns(cum_max_sum=pl.col('minimum').g('to_add'))[0:8])
```

Comment: Would be nice to have a ufunc with more than 2 inputs

Comment: It's not that you can't, you just have to pack all the inputs into a struct and then use the `struct[column]` syntax

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.with_columns(cum_max_sum = pl.max_horizontal('prev_cum_max_sum', 'minimum') + pl.col('to_add'))
```

Comment: I think the inclusion of `prev_cum_max_sum` is illustrative and they need for the expressions to only use `minimum` and `to_add`

Comment: Yes we only have the minimum and to_add columns