# How to compute a new Polars column based on its previous value

Tags: python, python-polars

I have the following problem in Pola.rs which I have not been able to resolve satisfactorily. I have the need to compute a new column on a dataframe, where each new value is based on the previous row value (via an expression).

Is there a way to pass the previous value to a row computation?

Concrete example. Consider the following dataframe.

| Time | Minutes |
| --- | --- |
| t[0] | m[0] |
| t[1] | m[1] |
| ... | ... |
| t[n] | t[n] |

The problem: compute a new `Event` column (or `e` for short below) columns as follows:

```
        /
        |  e[i-1], if t[i] > e[i-1]
e[i] = <.  
        |  t[i] + m[i] otherwise 
        \
```

What is the most pythonic/polaric way to do this?

Right now I am using [map_rows](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.map_rows.html#polars.DataFrame.map_rows) which seems really inefficient (because of the call to the Python function).

Comment: Can you add example inputs and expected output?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77001362/21444059) help?

Comment: @keraion it does help, thanks! I understand that it is impossible to this type of operation in a vectorized fashion, but if Polars provides some machinery to provide me with the previous value, at least I save on the zillion python function invocations (since the expression could be in Polars expression language). Will read your suggestion to find alternatives.

Comment: There's not, I can't say anything nice about the guy that wrote the answer that @keraion referenced but that answer is probably your best bet. It should be quite performant as well because it isn't impossible to vectorize the operation. The answer shows you how to vectorize it.

Comment: It's probably quicker to use `.iter_rows()` and do it in plain Python compared to `.map_rows()` - perhaps you could post a test case to benchmark. There is [`pl.cumfold`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cumfold.html#polars.cumfold) but it is a column-wise operation. You could also write the loop in Rust as a plugin/extension: https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars

Answer (score 0):

If using the Lazy API (which you should), you can use [`polars.Expr.shift`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.shift.html#polars.Expr.shift) to get `e[i-1]` in the current row, and then use ordinary `Expr`-based operations.

```py
import polars as pl
from numpy.random import randint

n = 10

df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {"e": randint(0, 10, n), "m": randint(0, 10, n), "t": randint(0, 10, n)}
    )
    .lazy()
    .with_columns(pl.col("e").shift(1).alias("e_1"))
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("t") > pl.col("e_1"))
        .then(pl.col("e_1"))
        .otherwise(pl.col("t") + pl.col("m"))
        .alias("Event")
    )
)

df.collect()
```

(Random) result:

```
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ e   ┆ m   ┆ t   ┆ e_1  ┆ Event │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ null ┆ 5     │
│ 9   ┆ 5   ┆ 1   ┆ 4    ┆ 6     │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 9    ┆ 7     │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 0   ┆ 2    ┆ 6     │
│ 0   ┆ 6   ┆ 2   ┆ 2    ┆ 8     │
│ 0   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 0    ┆ 0     │
│ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 5   ┆ 0    ┆ 0     │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 2    ┆ 2     │
│ 6   ┆ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 3    ┆ 2     │
│ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ 2   ┆ 6    ┆ 9     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not think this answer the question. I see the following issue: "shift" is not dynamic (i.e. "e_1" is computed ahead of time), so by the time we try to use it to compute "e" it does not have the right values. Am I misunderstanding the dynamic nature of "shift" in lazy dataframes?

Comment: Oh, I see — you need `e[i-1]` to update at each step. I'd need to think about this.

Comment: LazyFrames are not required to use shift.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor no, but you probably want to be using them in general (unless you have to iterate row-wise, as it looks like you do here).

Answer (score 0):

There is a horizontal (column-wise) version: [`pl.cumfold`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cumfold.html)

Technically, you could reshape your data and use it, however, it is computationally expensive and with the added cost of reshaping the data, it's not a scalable approach.

(This is presumably why there is no vertical equivalent in the API.)

As for using `.map_rows()`, it's probably quicker to just unpack with  [`.iter_rows()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.iter_rows.html#polars.DataFrame.iter_rows) and do the calculation in plain Python (if you're not using LazyFrames).

If that approach is too slow, it is also possible to write the loop in Rust: https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars

There is a [new Plugin API](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/10924) which aims to simplify adding custom behaviour from the Rust side.

[A modification of the `derive_expression` example](https://github.com/cmdlineluser/polars-plugin-example):

```py
import polars as pl
from expression_lib import Accumulate

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Time": [5, 3, 4, 1, 2],
    "Minutes": [2, 1, 2, 1, 3],
})

print(
    df.with_columns(
       cum_min_time = pl.col("Time").accumulate.min_time("Minutes")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬──────────────┐
│ Time ┆ Minutes ┆ cum_min_time │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ i64  ┆ i64     ┆ i64          │
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 5    ┆ 2       ┆ 7            │
│ 3    ┆ 1       ┆ 4            │
│ 4    ┆ 2       ┆ 4            │
│ 1    ┆ 1       ┆ 2            │
│ 2    ┆ 3       ┆ 2            │
└──────┴─────────┴──────────────┘
```

This just unpacks both Series and uses [`Iterator::scan()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) for a "vertical cumfold".

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3_polars::derive::polars_expr;

#[polars_expr(output_type=Int64)]
fn min_time(inputs: &[Series]) -> PolarsResult<Series> {
    let time = inputs[0].i64()?;
    let minutes = inputs[1].i64()?;

    let initial_value = time.get(0).unwrap() + minutes.get(0).unwrap();

    let out = time
        .into_iter()
        .zip(minutes.into_iter())
        .scan(initial_value, |state, (time, minutes)| {
            let time = time?;
            let minutes = minutes?;
            if *state > time {
                *state = time + minutes
            }
            Some(*state)
        })
        .collect();
    Ok(out)
}
```

Not a Rust/Polars-internals expert, so it's possible it could be improved upon - but it may serve as an interesting example.