# How should I perform operations on vectors/matrices in Polars

Tags: vectorization, python-polars

Looking for a polars-way to perform operations on vectors (List/Array) and matrices (List(List)/Array(Array)) .
`polars-0.19.9`

Small df

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "a": [[1,2], [3,4]],
   "b": [[10, 20], [30, 40]]
})
```

1. Seems like polars does not support operations on `lists/arrays`:

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("a") + pl.col("b"))
PanicException: `add` operation not supported for dtype `list[i64]`
```

2. However it does support operations on `structs` (was very surprised):

```
df.with_columns((pl.col("a").list.to_struct() + pl.col("b").list.to_struct()).alias("sum"))
```

3. For vectors we probably can use explode + group_by + join with the downside of executing the join:

```
df = df.with_row_count('i')

c = (
  df
    .select(["a", "b", "i"])  # required to not explode other cols in frame
    .explode(['a','b'])
    .groupby('i')
    .agg(c=pl.col('a')+pl.col('b'))
    .select(['i','c'])
)

df = df.join(c, on="i"). # but now we need to join resulting col back to frame
```

4. Another way to do it for vector is to explode + group_by(maintain_order) + hstack - this drops the need to join:

```
df = df.with_row_count('i')

c = (
  df
    .select(["a", "b", "i"])  # required to not explode other cols in frame
    .explode(['a','b'])
    .groupby('i', maintain_order=True). # allows to use hstack
    .agg(c=pl.col('a')+pl.col('b'))
    .select(['c'])
)

df = df.hstack(c)
```

5. Apply/map_elements with lists conversions to numpy array does not seem to be option at all, Polars use only one core when executing apply (however VAEX claim to be able to parallelise apply operations on multiple threads) + to my understanding there is no zero-copy happening:

```
import numpy as np

df.with_columns(
   pl.struct(["a", "b"])
   .apply(lambda x: (np.array(x["a"]) + np.array(x["b"])).tolist())
   .alias("c")
)
```

What would be the recommendation here - which way is considered to be more polars?
How should I deal with cases when I have nested lists/arrays in a row/col ? Doing multiple rounds of explode + group_by seems to be hardly manageable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your number 3 can be made a bit more concise like this:

```
(
  df.with_row_count('i')
    .explode(['a','b'])
    .group_by('i')
    .agg('a','b',c=pl.col('a')+pl.col('b'))
    .drop('i')
)
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ a         ┆ b         ┆ c         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2]    ┆ [10, 20]  ┆ [11, 22]  │
│ [3, 4]    ┆ [30, 40]  ┆ [33, 44]  │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Either this or the struct way are probably the best. You'd have to benchmark it to be sure.

<strike>You could try to make a ufunc with numba and the guvectorize decorator but I'm not sure if numba supports getting a list dtype so it might be a wild goose chase. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000439/cum-max-sum-in-polars/77001362#77001362)'s an example of numba with polars for a different application as a starting point. If you do this, please post it as an answer, I want to see it.</strike>

Using numba here won't work. polars doesn't support converting a list to a C-type for the ufunc to ingest. Even taking a `Series.to_arrow()` into a ufunc will error out. I think this is a limitation on ufuncs not being 100% interoperable with all of polars types rather than it being a polars shortcoming that could be upgraded on the polars side but I could easily be mistaken here.

**Another idea that does work:** is to round trip it through numpy

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        c=pl.Series([
            pl.Series(x[0] + x[1]) 
            # Even though we're using column indices above, 
            # we can make the columns in whichever position
            # we want using by ordering them in select so this 
            # works even with a lot of columns
            for x in df.select('a','b').to_numpy()
            ])
        )
    )
```

**Another potential goose chase:**

I forgot earlier that [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars) exists. You can write your expression in rust, compile it, and then have custom vectorized expressions.

Comment: thank you @dean-macgregor, here is what I get (same as with trying some numpy options):

ComputeError: custom python function failed: conversion of polars data type List to C-type not implemented

Comment: You get that running what I put above or something with numba?

Comment: numba, pasting, sorry for formatting:  

import numba as nb

@nb.guvectorize([(nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:], nb.int64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n)', nopython=True)
def g(x,y, res):
    for i in range(len(x)):
      res[i]=x[i]+y[i]

df.with_columns(cum_max_sum=g(pl.col('a'), pl.col('b')))

Comment: Yeah like I said, I'm not sure how to (or even if it'll work) get a list type into a numba datatype. That was just an idea to explore.

Comment: Thank you, its good to know numba would work. I guess the problem is on Polars side here of not being able to pass its list type.

Comment: I'm not saying numba would work but for polars being unable to pass a list type. They're two distinct libraries that have dissimilar underlying memory structures. It may be that there isn't a common supertype between a polars list and anything that numba supports but that's not "on polars".

Comment: I see. I thought its on polars side as numpy ufuncs, which are referred in Polars User Guid fail with the same error on lists: df.with_columns(np.multiply(pl.col("a"), pl.col("b"))). Unfortunately I have not found in documentation anything about limitation that ufuncs can work on scalars only.

Comment: It seems to be a limitation on ufuncs. They have methods that make it so you can use Series in place of numpy arrays and so that numpy arrays can be safely returned without explicitly casting to Series first. It seems the degree to which that works is limited to unnested structures like lists. That said, I put another idea in the answer and crossed out the numba one.