# Is there a way to add a column of numpy random values to a polars dataframe while one column is an input to numpy.random?

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

Let's say I have a dataframe that has a column named `mean` that I want to use as an input to a random number generator. Coming from R, this is relatively easy to do in a pipeline:

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(alpha = rnorm(1000),
       beta = rnorm(1000)) %>%
  mutate(mean = alpha + beta) %>%
  bind_cols(random_output = rnorm(n = nrow(.), mean = .$mean, sd = 1))
#> # A tibble: 1,000 × 4
#>     alpha   beta    mean random_output
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1  0.231 -0.243 -0.0125         0.551
#>  2  0.213  0.647  0.861          0.668
#>  3  0.824 -0.353  0.471          0.852
#>  4  0.665 -0.916 -0.252         -1.81 
#>  5 -0.850  0.384 -0.465         -3.90 
#>  6  0.721  0.679  1.40           2.54 
#>  7  1.46   0.857  2.32           2.14 
#>  8 -0.242 -0.431 -0.673         -0.820
#>  9  0.234  0.188  0.422         -0.662
#> 10 -0.494 -2.15  -2.65          -3.01 
#> # ℹ 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In python, I can create an intermediate dataframe and use it as input to `np.random.normal()`, then bind that to the dataframe, but this feels clunky. Is there a way to add the `random_output` col as a part of the pipeline/chain?

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

# create a df
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "alpha": np.random.standard_normal(1000),
            "beta": np.random.standard_normal(1000)
        }
    )
    .with_columns(
        (pl.col("alpha") + pl.col("beta")).alias("mean")
    )
    
)

# create an intermediate object
sim_vals = np.random.normal(df.get_column("mean"))

# bind the simulated values to the original df
(
    df.with_columns(random_output = pl.lit(sim_vals))
)
#> shape: (1_000, 4)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────────┐
│ alpha     ┆ beta      ┆ mean      ┆ random_output │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---           │
│ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64           │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ -1.380249 ┆ 1.531959  ┆ 0.15171   ┆ 0.938207      │
│ -0.332023 ┆ -0.108255 ┆ -0.440277 ┆ 0.081628      │
│ -0.718319 ┆ -0.612187 ┆ -1.330506 ┆ -1.286229     │
│ 0.22067   ┆ -0.497258 ┆ -0.276588 ┆ 0.908147      │
│ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …             │
│ 0.299117  ┆ -0.371846 ┆ -0.072729 ┆ 0.592632      │
│ 0.789633  ┆ 0.95712   ┆ 1.746753  ┆ 2.954801      │
│ -0.264415 ┆ -0.761634 ┆ -1.026049 ┆ -1.369753     │
│ 1.893911  ┆ 1.554736  ┆ 3.448647  ┆ 5.192537      │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: You could skip the explicit assignment of the intermediate object to `sim_vals` and use `df.with_columns(random_output=pl.lit(np.random.normal(df.get_column("mean")))`. I don't think it gets better than that.

Comment: There is also `.map_batches` e.g. `df.with_columns(random_output = pl.col("mean").map_batches(lambda col: pl.Series(np.random.normal(col))))` - Anyone know why `.normal` behaves like a ufunc but isn't "registered" as one? If it was you could `.with_columns(np.random.normal(pl.col("mean")))`

Comment: @jqurious I'm not sure what you mean that it behaves like a ufunc.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology. How come we can do `np.exp(pl.col("mean"))` but not `np.random.normal(pl.col("mean"))`

Comment: `np.exp` is a ufunc so you're using the right terminology. You can see this by doing `type(np.exp)` whereas `np.random.normal` is not. I just didn't know what you meant by saying it *behaves **like** a ufunc*.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor As in, if I pass a 2d array to `np.random.normal` I get the same shape back. I thought that was the general gist of what a ufunc is, but I guess not.

Comment: @jqurious I see. Yeah I think it's not a ufunc because it's *too* flexible. For instance not only are you able to pass it a 1d array and get a similarly shaped 1d array but you can also pass it `np.random.normal(0,1,10000)` to get a 1d 10,000 element array even though it didn't receive a 10000 element array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four approaches (that I can think of), 2 of which were mentioned in comments, one that I use, and the last I know it exists but don't personally use it.

#### First (get_column(col) or ['col']) reference

Use `df.get_column` as a parameter of `np.random.normal` which you can do in a chain if you use `pipe` so for example

```
df.with_columns(
    mean=pl.col('alpha') + pl.col('beta')
).pipe(lambda df: (
    df.with_columns(
        rando=pl.lit(np.random.normal(df['mean']))
    )
))
```

#### Second (map_batches)

Use `map_batches` as an expression

```
df.with_columns(
    mean=pl.col('alpha') + pl.col('beta')
).with_columns(
    rando=pl.col('mean').map_batches(lambda col: pl.Series(np.random.normal(col)))
)
```

#### Third (numba)

This approach is the faster than the previous two if you're going to do many randomizations but takes more setup (hence the caveat about many randomizations)

numba lets you create ufuncs which are compiled functions which you can use directly inside an expression.

You can create this function which just uses the default standard deviation

```
import numba as nb
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:])], '(n)->(n)', nopython=True)
def rando(means,  res):
    for i in range(len(means)):
        res[i]=np.random.normal(means[i])
```

then you can do

```
df.with_columns(
    mean=pl.col('alpha') + pl.col('beta')
).with_columns(rand_nb=rando(pl.col('mean')))
```

More reading:

[guvectorize](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator)

[another numba example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000439/cum-max-sum-in-polars/77001362#77001362)

[limitation](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10512)

#### Fourth (rust extension)

Unfortunately for this answer (and I suppose myself in general) I haven't dabbled in rust programming but there's an extension interface whereby you can create functions in rust and deploy them as expressions. [Here is documentation on doing that](https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars)

### Performance

Using a 1M row df I get...

First method: 71.1 ms ± 8.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Second method: 70.7 ms ± 7.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Third method: 45.7 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

One thing to note is that it's not faster unless you want a different mean for each row, for instance...

`df.with_columns(z=rando(pl.repeat(5,pl.count())))`: 43.8 ms ± 2.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

`df.with_columns(z=pl.Series(np.random.normal(5,1,df.shape[0])))`: 39.6 ms ± 3.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)