How to recursively calculate a column based on previous row values of another column in Polars?
I'm trying to calculate a weighted_goals column in a DataFrame using the Polars library in Python. I want each row's weighted_goals your textvalue to depend on previous values of a column called goals, calculated for each team using a group-based window (over("Team")).
The formula I’m aiming to implement is something like this:

For each row:

weighted_goals = 0.8 * goals[n] + 0.2 * (0.8 * goals[n-1] + 0.2 * (0.8 * goals[n-2] ...)
The idea is for weighted_goals to be a recursive calculation that takes into account previous values in goals for each team, with an exponential decay (or weighting) at each step.
To illustrate, suppose I have the following DataFrame:
import polars as pl

data = pl.DataFrame({
    "Team": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Week": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    "goals": [2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2]
})

For this input, I would like the weighted_goals column to look something like this (using the recursive formula mentioned above):



Team
Week
goals
weighted_goals




A
1
2
2


A
2
1
0.8 * 1 + 0.2 * 2 = 1.2


A
3
3
0.8 * 3 + 0.2 * (0.8 * 1 + 0.2 * 2) = 2.56


B
1
1
1


B
2
4
0.8 * 4 + 0.2 * 1 = 3.2


B
3
2
0.8 * 2 + 0.2 * (0.8 * 4 + 0.2 * 1) = 2.56



How can I implement this recursive formula in Polars? Is there an efficient way to achieve this without using an explicit loop?

This reads like you want to implement exponential smoothing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing), which Polars has implemented in ewm_mean. The formula in the docstring under "adjust=False" is what you described, but you will probably want "adjust=True".

In general, the name for this seems to be "veritical fold/scan" and you'd need to write it in Rust as a custom Polars Plugin: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12165#issuecomment-1892617149 - There's also some Polars+numba examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000439/

Using pandas, you can do this: data['weighted_data'] = data.groupby('Team')['goals'].ewm(alpha=.8, adjust=False).mean().to_numpy()

The Polars equivalent being: df.with_columns(pl.col("goals").ewm_mean(alpha=0.8, adjust=False).over("Team"))
